# How to remove a hyperbolic trignometric function from an equation

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

If I have an equation for example where y and z are known and x is unknown. It is of the form

z = sinh(x) +y

I want to write this equation of the form

x = y + z (some form of this)

Inorder to do this, I multiplied both sides by inverse hyperbolic sine function

sinh-1(z) = x + sinh-1(y)
x = sinh-1(z) - sinh-1(y);

I believe this does not work. As I did a small test in matlab (calculator) of multiplying sinh(1)*sinh-1(1). This did not give me a value as 1. Hence I believe this form of equation manipulation is wrong. Can anyone please suggest me a better way to do it.

Comment: What about $z-y=\sinh(x)$?

Comment: Try $x = \text{arcsinh}(z-y)$. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html