# How to divide a catenary curve into parts of equal length?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions, arc-length

I know the basic equation of a catenary is

y = a*cosh((x-x0)/a)+b

Length of a catenary curve is

L = a*sinh((x-x0)/a)

where x0 is a symmetry point or vertex or lowest x co-ordinate of a curve.

I can reverse manipulate using this length equation.

The small length Ln = (total length - length at a particular point)

Ln = a* [ sinh((x_start-x0)/a) - sinh((x_n-x0)/a) ]

where x_start is the starting point at one end of a catenary
x_n is the x co-ordinate at length Ln (small fixed length along the curve)

In this equation I know all the terms except x_n and hence I would like to rewrite this equation of the form xn = other terms.

I am unable to reverse this equation as I am not sure how to remove sinh in the equation, can anyone please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: Use the [arcsinh](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSinh/) function

Comment: Try to [format your equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make them more readable. That may increase the chances of someone providing an answer, because the question would be easier to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817521/how-to-remove-a-hyperbolic-trignometric-function-from-an-equation)